# Accessing the clicked element

Tags: javascript, pug

```
extends ../header2.pug
block unique-css
    include ../../public/css/mentor/mentiler.css
block unique-content
    .main
        each menti, index in mentiler
            .menti= menti
    script
        include ../../public/js/mentor/mentiler.js
```

This is my pug code and what I want is to access the clicked `.menti` classed element in

```
    each menti, index in mentiler
        .menti= menti
```

this lines of code with javascript. But the problem is when I add the eventlistener on class `.menti` it only works for the first element.

And here is my js code:

```
document.querySelector(".menti").addEventListener("click", () => 
{
    console.log(document.querySelector(".menti").innerHTML)
})
```

As I said above I can only get the first element.

Comment: This is an issue with your javascript code, not your Pug code. Please include your javascript code in the question.

Comment: `.querySelector()` will always only return the first matched element. Use `.querySelectorAll()` instead (check the return value in the documentation and how to work with it)

Comment: Yes, you need `document.querySelectorAll('.menti').forEach(el => { /* add click listener to el */ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`querySelector()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns the first element that it matches.

To bind an event to every `.menti` element, you'll need to use the [`querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) combined with a loop:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.menti').forEach(menti => {
  menti.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // handle click
  })
})
```